# Matrices java, columnas

Tags: java, java-8

Una consulta... tengo un ejercicio de matrices (matriz cuadrada) que pide verificar dos cosas:

1. Que en todas las filas exista algún múltiplo de 3.
2. Que alguna columna sea múltiplo de 5.

La parte de las filas me sale pero no sabría recorrer por columnas, ¿alguna ayuda?

Con este método verifico que exista un múltiplo de 3 en un arreglo:

```
static boolean multiplodeTres (int [] s) {
    boolean verdadero= false;
    for(int i=0; i< s.length;i++) {
        verdadero = verdadero || (s[i]%3 == 0);
    }
    return verdadero;
}
```

En el método principal uso el método anterior y me verifica que en cada fila exista un múltiplo de 3:

```
static boolean fila3col5(int[][] mat) {
    boolean res=true;
    for(int i=0; i< mat.length;i++) {
        res= res && (multiplodeTres(mat[i]));
    }
```

Mi problema seria verificar las columnas para encontrar una con un múltiplo de 5.

Comment: Hola, podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron útiles

Answer (score 0):

Entendamos primero las filas y columnas ya que estas confundido con esos términos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen anterior vemos que las filas son 0,1,2 mientras que las columnas son 0,2,3,4
Por lo tanto en ese ejemplo seria una matriz de 3 x 5

Pasamos a tus puntos:

1. Que en todas las filas exista algún múltiplo de 3.   (Esto se traduce a que por lo menos exista un múltiplo de 3 en todas las columnas de cada fila)
2. Que alguna columna sea múltiplo de 5. (Esto es lo mismo que el punto 1, que exista algún múltiplo de 5 en las columnas de cada fila).

Examinado los punto anteriores se crea el siguiente código.

```
  public class Matriz {
        public static void main (String args[]) {   
        int numeros[][] = new int [4][3]; //Esto es una matriz de 4  filas y 3 columnas
        //Definimos los valores de las columnas de la primera fila
        numeros[0][0] = 100;  
        numeros[0][1] = 200;
        numeros[0][2] = 400;

        //Definimos los valores de las columnas de la segunda fila    
        numeros[1][0] = 400;
        numeros[1][1] = 500;
        numeros[1][2] = 600;


        //Definimos los valores de las columnas de la tercera fila
        numeros[2][0] = 4;
        numeros[2][1] = 9;
        numeros[2][2] = 100;

        //Definimos los valores de las columnas de la cuarta fila           
        numeros[3][0] = 4;
        numeros[3][1] = 9;
        numeros[3][2] = 1;


        //f=fila
        for (int f = 0; f < numeros.length; f++ ) {                         
           
          if(multiplos(numeros[f],3)==0) {
               System.out.println("En la fila "+ (f+1) +" no existen multiplos de 3");
               break; //Si no se cumple las condiciones con el break se sale del ciclo
           }
           
           if(multiplos(numeros[f],5)==0) {
               System.out.println("En la fila "+ (f+1) +" no existen multiplos de 5");
               break;//Si no se cumple las condiciones con el break se sale del ciclo
           }

        }
    }
    
    
    //Metodo para validar si los valores son multiplos o no
    static int multiplos (int [] s, int valorAValidar ) {
        int valorValido= 0;
        for(int i=0; i< s.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("valor es = "+s[i] + " valor a validar = " +valorAValidar +"  resultado=="+ s[i]%valorAValidar);   
            if (s[i]%valorAValidar ==0) {
                valorValido++;
            }
        }
        return valorValido;
    }
    
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int contFilas = 0;
int contColumnas = 0;
bool multiplo3 = false;
bool multiplo5 = false;

for(int i = 0; i++; i < filas) //filas es la cantidad de filas que tiene la matriz
{
   multiplo3 = false;
   multiplo5 = false;
   
   for(int j = 0; j++; j < columnas)//columnas es la cantidad de columnas que tiene la matriz
   {
      if(matriz[i,j] % 3 == 0) //Filas
      {
         multiplo3 = true;
         break;
      }

      contFilas = (multiplo3) ? contFilas + 1 : contFilas;

      if(matriz[j,i] % 5 == 0) //Columnas
      {
         multiplo5 = true;
         break;
      }

      contColumnas = (multiplo5) ? contColumnas + 1 : contColumnas;
   }
}

String mensajeFilas = (contFilas == filas) ? 
                       "Hay al menos un multiplo de 3 por cada fila" :
                       "No se cumple la condicion de las filas";

String mensajeColumnas = (contColumnas == columnas) ? 
                          "Hay al menos un multiplo de 5 por cada columna" :
                          "No se cumple la condicion de las columnas";

System.out.println(mensajeFilas);
System.out.println(mensajeColumnas);
```

Se hacen dos **ciclos for anidados** y se pregunta para cada elemento de esa fila si hay algún **múltiplo de 3**, de haberlo la **variable multiplo3** toma **valor true**. Para preguntar por las filas se usa **matriz[i,j]** y para las columnas el inverso, **matriz[j,i]**. Mas abajo se pregunta si la **variable multiplo3** es **true**, de serlo se incrementa el contador de las filas, de no serlo se queda igual.

Para las columnas es el mismo procedimiento, se pregunta por cada elemento de la columna si hay algún **múltiplo de 5**, de haberlo la **variable multiplo5** toma el valor de **true**, después se pregunta si la **variable multiplo5** es **true**, de serlo se incrementa el contador de las columnas, de no serlo se queda igual.

Luego se pregunta si **contFilas** es igual a la cantidad de filas de la matriz, de serlo se imprime que se cumple la condición, de no serlo lo contrario.

Después se pregunta si **contColumnas** es igual a la cantidad de columnas de la matriz, de serlo se imprime que se cumple la condición, de no serlo lo contrario.